# Shuffle and partition a NumPy array into unequal parts

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have data in a 2D numpy array.I want to divide its rows into three sub sets of 60%,20%,20% sizes. I tried using numpy.split function, but it only create equal size sub arrays. I also tried KFold method in sklearn library, but it does not allow me to specify the subset sizes. And sklearn's shuffle split, only allows splitting into two subsets. I know I can split the data two times using shufflesplit to create three subsets, but I want to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Is the required split random?

Comment: @Baha Yes, I want it to shuffle rows before splitting,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.random.shuffle` and *then* assign slices.

```
x = ...
np.random.shuffle(x)
l = x.shape[0]
A, B, C = x[: int(l * .6)], x[int(l * .6) : int(l * .8)], x[int(l * .8):]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Shuffle the array
2. Split into 3 parts

---

```
import numpy
# assuming your dataset is like x: x for dataset
x = numpy.random.rand(100, 10)
# what you can do
numpy.random.shuffle(x)
split1, split2 = 60, 80
part1, part2, part3 = x[:split1,:], x[split1:split2,:], x[split2:,:]
```